# Custom URL Helper redirect with get method

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my codeigniter **application/helper/MY_url_helper** I would like to be able to add `'?&route=' . $uri` I would like to be able to use my `'?&route='` after the index.php but before the first folder / function.

But every time I click on my link the url changes but the page stays the same?

**Question:** On my helper how can I add `'?&route=' . $uri` but make it still redirect to page
currently each time even when I click on link the url changes but page stays the same?

`redirect('common/dashboard');`

Url `http://localhost/project/admin/?&route=common/dashboard`

I have tried it with routes and same issue.

```
<?php

if ( ! function_exists('redirect'))
{
function redirect($uri = '', $method = 'auto', $code = NULL)
{
    //if ( ! preg_match('#^(\w+:)?//#i', $uri))
    //{
        $uri = site_url('?&route=' . $uri);
    //}

    // IIS environment likely? Use 'refresh' for better compatibility
    if ($method === 'auto' && isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Microsoft-IIS') !== FALSE)
    {
        $method = 'refresh';
    }
    elseif ($method !== 'refresh' && (empty($code) OR ! is_numeric($code)))
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] === 'HTTP/1.1')
        {
            $code = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'GET')
                ? 303   // reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get
                : 307;
        }
        else
        {
            $code = 302;
        }
    }

    switch ($method)
    {
        case 'refresh':
            header('Refresh:0;url='.$uri);
            break;
        default:
            header('Location: '.$uri, TRUE, $code);
            break;
    }
    exit;
}
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Update:**

Version Of Codeigniter Using 3

In my config I now use

Tried With

`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';`

And

`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';`

But then now saying page not found?

Page is there though.

Also **"common"** would be folder

And **"dashboard"** would be controller

All controllers have the first letter as upper case Dashboard.php

**Note:** I have tried to ***enable query strings*** on the config.php but does not work way I am after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First steps I had to do to solve it was

In routes.php

```
$get_route_method = 'route=';
$route[$get_route_method . 'common/dashboard'] = "common/dashboard/index";
```

Seems to work fine now when I manually added route in application/config/route.php

Then in MY_url_helper in application/helper.php `$uri = site_url('index.php?route=' . $uri);`

```
<?php

if ( ! function_exists('redirect'))
{
function redirect($uri = '', $method = 'auto', $code = NULL)
{
    if ( ! preg_match('#^(\w+:)?//#i', $uri))
    {
        $uri = site_url('index.php?route=' . $uri);
    }

    // IIS environment likely? Use 'refresh' for better compatibility
    if ($method === 'auto' && isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Microsoft-IIS') !== FALSE)
    {
        $method = 'refresh';
    }
    elseif ($method !== 'refresh' && (empty($code) OR ! is_numeric($code)))
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] === 'HTTP/1.1')
        {
            $code = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'GET')
                ? 303   // reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get
                : 307;
        }
        else
        {
            $code = 302;
        }
    }

    switch ($method)
    {
        case 'refresh':
            header('Refresh:0;url='.$uri);
            break;
        default:
            header('Location: '.$uri, TRUE, $code);
            break;
    }
    exit;
}
}
```